# Algorithm Question: Stacking bricks of different colours?

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I have a bunch of coloured bricks. There are X different colours, and a random number of each colour. How do I stack them up into Y columns so that a) no row has two bricks of the same colour and b) the height of the *largest* column is minimised?

There is an obvious lower bound of highest number of bricks of a single colour but beyond that I don't know where to go. This is equivalent to an optimisation problem I'm trying to solve and I'd be grateful if someone recognised the problem!

Comment: If you don't know the total number of bricks of each color, does that mean you don't know *anything* about the future bricks at the time you're making a decision about the current brick? That seems like it would make it very difficult to get an optimal solution, since you could get a bunch of bricks of the same color at the end, which would ruin an optimally stacked solution for the earlier bricks.

Comment: I know all the bricks at the time I start stacking them, but not in advance (at coding time). Without knowledge of future bricks, you could definitely end up with a suboptimal final solution unless you restart placing them again.

Comment: Does allocating a column for each color solves the problem ?

Comment: No, because Y can be less than X. With Y >= X, the problem is trivial, just allocate a column per colour. But with Y < X, it's non-trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of bricks and $c_i$ be the number of bricks of color $i$.
First notice that in a $w \times h$ grid we can fit at most $wh$ bricks.
Therefore, $\lceil \frac{n}{Y} \rceil$ is a lower bound on your height. The
minimum height $h$ to stack all your bricks without violating the constraint will be
$\max(\max_i(c_i), \lceil \frac{n}{Y} \rceil)$.

The idea is to go from left to right (column 1 to X) and keep pushing a brick of the same color on to the left most non-full stack. And by non-full I mean that the size of the stack is lower than our defined height $h$. No two colors will be in the same row and it is also obviously true, that we have enough room for all $n$ bricks.

A pseudo code is also provided:

```
color_count[i] = number of bricks of color i
height = max(max(color_count), ceil(n / Y))

current_column = 1
current_row = 1
current_color = 1
while current_color <= X
  while color_count[current_color] > 0
    put a brick at (current_row, current_column) with current_color
    color_count[current_color] -= 1
    if current_row == height
      current_column += 1
      current_row = 1
    else
      current_row += 1
  current_color += 1
```

Comment: Nice! Yeah, I can see that the other lower bound is also true, and we get the $\max(\max_i(c_i), \lceil \frac{n}{Y} \rceil)$ - then you're right, if we just sort by $c_i$ then just by filling each column as we go we can a) never have a duplicate in any row, because there aren't enough to wrap around and b) we always fit all of the bricks. This way, we've proved that the bricks always fit with Y equal to the lower bound and thus this solution is optimal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution, but don't know if it's correct. Here are the steps :

Let $C$ be the array that stores the colors, and $Y$ the one for the columns, with $Y_i$ the height of column $i$.

1. Count for each color the number of bricks that have this color.
2. Sort $C$ in descending order according to the number of bricks of each color.
3. Create a first column, and put in it all the bricks of color $c_1$.
4. Create a new empty column.
5. Now, fill the new empty column with bricks of color $c_2$. Because $C$ is sorted in descending order, after filling this column, $Y_2 \leq Y_1$.
6. Continue to fill the last column with next bricks until $Y_1 = Y_2$. When finish, create a new empty column.
7. Repeat 5 with the rest of the bricks.

Here's an example :

[image]

First iteration :

[image]

First column is full with all the bricks of color 1.

Second iteration :

[image]

We have put all the bricks of color 2. We have an empty cell, we can put a brick of color 3 and create a new column.

[image]

We now fill the new column with the rest of the bricks.

[image]

Comment: Ah sorry, you may have misunderstood - the number of columns is fixed, and I want the height of the column to be minimised. So imagine this, except there could only be at most two columns - your minimum height there is 6. Then find the general solution. Looks like we already have an optimal answer though, above ^